# Pyton3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyAesCrypt'

Tags: pyinstaller, modulenotfounderror

We created a simple program using the [pyAesCrypt module](https://pypi.org/project/pyAesCrypt/) and built it using pyinstaller on macOS and Windows, respectively.

However, when you run a built-up program, you get the error as below.

> ```
> MacBookPro:dist Xeros$ ./XCryptor -i test.txt  Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File "XCryptor.py", line 5, in <module>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyAesCrypt' [7105] Failed to
> execute script XCryptor
> ```

This error occurs on both macOS and Windows operating systems.

There is no problem with my code and it works normally when executed with an interpreter.

I tried to add the pyAesCrypt module directly using the hidden import option, but it still does not work.

How can we solve this?

Comment: I tried it without any command and didn't have any problem. Maybe upgrading PyInstaller will help.

Comment: thx The pyaescrypt module was directly ejected and used to resolve it. Maybe it's a problem setting the environment variables on my system.